# Bad Tiling - Painting with texture

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-painting

So i am painting with texture on my object and problem is that my texture is not repeating correctly (1 next to other) but they overlap (almost like random but not that fast).

Here is texture i am using (self made) 
[image]

Here is result Here is result
[image]

Comment: What happens if you use the same brush and settings to paint onto a simple plane, and what also happens when painting onto a new image in the UV image editor? Is the tile still 'overlapped'?

Comment: They are still overlaping

Comment: Have to ask - what does the image mapping look like there in the brush texture panel? It is closed right now, can't see it.

Comment: You see it on the left side in UV window

Comment: How about when you open the brush image alone in the UV image editor and switch on 'repeat' under the Display tab in Coordinates in the UV image editor? Do you get a perfect tiling going on? Can you try with a different tiled image from the internet as a test? I try to reproduce it here, and I cannot.

Comment: i found other much easier way to do it but still i continued researching this. When i do that in UV editor and zoom in i get normal image on repeat but when i zoom out further and further SOME black lines get tighter and tighter but some stay thick so when i set brush to large it paint normal (but bricks are too large) but when i zoom down i get this.